# Phantom /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd /dev/sde /dev/sdf on every boot

Tags: mount, udev

I have several "phantom" /dev/sdX entries that don't point to any hardware:

```
~$ ls -l /dev/sd*
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8,  0 May  3 11:04 /dev/sda
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8,  1 May  3 11:04 /dev/sda1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8,  2 May  7 16:29 /dev/sda2
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 16 May  7 16:11 /dev/sdb
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 32 May  3 11:04 /dev/sdc
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 48 May  3 11:04 /dev/sdd
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 64 May  3 11:04 /dev/sde
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 80 May  3 11:04 /dev/sdf

$ lsblk /dev/sdb
NAME MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sdb    8:16   1   0B  0 disk
```

/dev/sdaX is real, but the others do not exist.  There is nothing in dmesg or "fdisk -l" for any of them.  When I insert a new USB drive, it gets assigned /dev/sdg.

What is causing these drives to appear, and how do I get rid of them?  I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you running, what computer is it, and is there some card reader or some similar device connected? (I have a USB card reader that creates empty block devices like that.)

Comment: That was it!  I had a USB card reader attached that I completely completely forgot about.  If you post that as an answer, I will give you credit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a USB card reader that creates empty block devices like that. So please check if you have a card reader, USB hub or similar device connected.